# Windows XP "The Handle is invalid" when opening .lnk file

Tags: html, windows-xp

We have recently setup a new print server on a 2008 r2 box. I do not want to use the built in IIS printer page that is available. We already have an intranet site that I want our users to go to for the printer installs.

What I found works on Windows 7 is giving a "The handle is invalid" in Windows XP

I have made a file printer.lnk and placed it in the document root of the intranet server the the target of the .lnk file is \\printserver\printer so on the site i put in

```
<a href="printer.lnk"><span>Office Printer</span></a>
```

so in essense when you click on "Office Printer" it prompts you to save or run the file printer.lnk

When I click "Open" in Windows 7 it begins installing the printer normally.

When I click "Run" in Windows XP  with Internet Explorer 8 I get an error of "The handle is invalid"
If i close the error window and click the link again then click "Run" again it works just fine... I dont wan't that to be the answer to this problem.

Any suggestions or possibly a better all arround solution. I'm a network guy and I am not great at html so please try and keep solutions simple if possible.

Comment: What happens when you right-click on the link and select "Save target as", then start this saved file. Does it work or does it fail also? Is the Win 7 box already on IE9 or is it also using IE8?

Comment: Windows 7 is running IE 9. It does work in Windows XP using Firefox(of course), but I am not going to deploy Firefox thorugh out or agency because I can not manage the settings through AD. Yes it does work if you do a save as to the desktop and then run it. I just would prefer a way to make the link work becuase I know I am going to get calls on this if the users have to right-click and save even if I post instructions on the site.

Comment: Thanks. So "Save target as" + starting the file is working with Firefox, but in IE8 it fails the same way as if you click directly on the link?

Answer (score 0):

Just to recap what we know so far:

- Windows 7 with IE9: Click works
- Windows XP with Firefox: Click works
- Windows XP with IE8: Click does **not** work (Save Target as and
  executing it works)

Given this information, I think that IE8 fails at trying to detect what file type a shortcut (*.LNK) is and it is using MIME-sniffing to find out. A long description of this can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In short, it means that IE reads the file and tries to *guess* what type it is and which program is needed to open it.

You could overcome this by adding a MIME type for LNK to the web server, so no MIME-sniffing is needed. See [this blog post from Darren McCall](http://darrenmccall.com/blog/2010/04/13/shortcut-lnk-to-pdf-with-iis/) for details.